# Is $\log \circ f \circ \exp$ concave when $f$ is concave, positive and increasing?

Tags: derivatives, convex-analysis

I believe that $\log \circ f \circ \exp$ should be concave if $f$ is positive, increasing and concave. My intuitive reasoning is that since it is true (in a degenerate sense) for $f(x) = x$, a fortiori it must be true if $f$ is strictly concave.

However, I'm not sure how to prove this. Any idea or counter-example?

Comment: Is $f$ assumed to be $C^2$?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven, for my particular problem, yes, I can assume $f$ to be $C^2$

Comment: Hint: $\log e^\frac xn=\frac xn\,.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that for $f(x)=x^a$ then $g(x)=\ln(f(e^x))=ax$ is always linear, so intuition is biased.

But just take $f(x)=x+\sqrt{x}\ $ this doesn't go so well...

$f''(x)=-\dfrac 1{4x\sqrt{x}}<0$

$g''(x)=\dfrac{e^{3x/2}}{4(e^x+e^{x/2})^2}>0$

Comment: That answers it, thanks!